# Relations between an object, its constructor and its methods

Tags: javascript

this is #33 from John Resig`s Learning Advanced JavaScript. http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#33   Would appreciate as much help as you can provide on this.

1) technically speaking, is `ninja.changeName("Bob")`  "calling" the function Ninja, or does it go immediately to `this.changeName(name);`

2) Once `ninja.changeName("Bob")` is invoked, what is the order in which the processing events take place inside function Ninja(name)?

3) what exactly is the purpose/function of    this.changeName ( name);

```
function Ninja(name){
  this.changeName = function(name){
    this.name = name;
  };

  this.changeName( name );
}

var ninja = new Ninja("John");
assert( ninja.name == "John", "The name has been set on initialization" );

ninja.changeName("Bob");
assert( ninja.name == "Bob", "The name was successfully changed." );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) technically speaking, is
>   ninja.changeName("Bob") "calling" the
>   function Ninja, or does it go
>   immediately to this.changeName(name);

The function `Ninja` can be only called with the syntax `Ninja(..)`. The syntax `new Ninja(...)` doesn't exactly call the function, it uses it as a constructor for a new object. And the syntax `ninja.changeName("Bob")` calls the anonymous function attached to the `changeName` property of the `ninja` object by its `Ninja` constructor. `ninja.changeName("Bob")` has very few things to do with the `Ninja` function, "technically speaking". Once the object `ninja` has been created, there is no relation *at all* between `ninja.changeName` and `Ninja`.

Returning to your question: **neither**. It doesn't "call" the function `Ninja`, and it doesn't go to `this.changeName(name)`. It simply calls the function `ninja.changeName`, which is a regular, anonymous function, referenced by a property of our object `ninja`.

> 2) Once ninja.changeName("Bob") is
>   invoked, what is the order in which
>   the processing events take place
>   inside function Ninja(name)?

As written above, there's **no relation** between the two. Executing `ninja.changeName("Bob")` does a `call` on the anonymous function referenced by `ninja.changeName`. The association between `ninja.changeName` and the anonymous function `function(name) { this.name=name; }` has been set by the constructor `Ninja`, but that's the only relation between them.

> 3) what exactly is the
>   purpose/function of this.changeName (
>   name);

The function `changeName` is called in the constructor to show you that a method can be called inside the constructor. You can create setters for an object, then use these setters in the constructor to initialize the object's properties. The example is didactic ; in the real world, setters can be quite complicated, and you *have* to use them to initialize the object. And besides, what would be the point of creating a setter if don't use it, like in :

```
function Ninja(constructorArg) {
  this.changeName = function(setterArg){
    this.name = setterArg;
  };
  this.name = constructorArg; // I'm not using the setter I've just written
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) It is calling the method on the function.

2) It simply updates its own `name` property via the setter.

3) It is to use a setter to change a property.

Answer (score 1):

this is very good question)

- in JS functions are objects, so by calling `ninja.changeName("Bob")` you go straight to ninja's method `.changeName()`
- if `ninja.changeName` was called no actions outside this method will be fired
- `this.changeName ( name);` - is constructor actions, they are applied to ninja object on creation only (to extend the newly created object with property name)

take a look at [this great book on OOP in JS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847194141)

Answer (score 1):

> 1) technically speaking, is ninja.changeName("Bob") "calling" the function Ninja, or does it go immediately to this.changeName(name);

It calls the anonymous function that is assigned to the `changeName` property of the instance of Ninja that is created with `var ninja = new Ninja("John");`.

> 2) Once ninja.changeName("Bob") is invoked, what is the order in which the processing events take place inside function Ninja(name)?

The single statement in that function is run

> 3) what exactly is the purpose/function of this.changeName ( name);

It takes one argument, and assigns the value of that argument to the `name` property of the instance of `Ninja` on which the method is called.